# how the wait command works in cypress

Tags: wait, cypress

This happens all the time, even if I change the timeout

```
it( 'Lab', ()=> {
            cy.server();
            cy.route('POST', 'https://apigateway.specimensecure.com:447/sivah/icore_lab_test/employees/findFirstByGenericId?genericId=146').as ('labRequest');
            cy.visit('https://lab.specimensecure.com:447/#/');
            cy.url().should('include', '/lab');
            // cy.wait('@labRequest').its('status').should('eq', 200);
            cy.wait('@labRequest')
            cy.get(':nth-child(10) > .nav-link > .fa').click();  
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKf56.png)

Comment: version 3.4.1 cypress

Comment: When looking at your command log, I see no request to `apigateway`. If there was one, it would show up in the log. If the `click` triggers this requiest, you must switch the lines `wait` and `click`